# CORS setup with two tomcat servers

Tags: tomcat, web, cors

I'm having a difficult time getting CORS setup between two servers.  I have two domains running locally: localhost:8080 and localhost:8081.  I am trying to load 8081 in an iframe in 8080.

I've modified 8081 to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* to the response headers and I've checked that they're present in chrome developer tools.  Yet I still get errors indicating a CORS problem.  Here is the error in the console:

```
"Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8081" from accessing a cross-origin frame."
```

Am I missing something here?  I've read a lot about enabling CORS and the various guides all indicate that this is all I should need.

Thanks.

Comment: I noticed you are using 8080 and 8081, are you installing an atlassian application, by chance?

Comment: 8081 is actually dotCMS.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a promising resource.  This company has created an open source CORS library for Java servers, and then you just have to edit your web.xml file for that instance.  Here are the instructions for installing it:

http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html